# Как задать относительный путь к видео файлу для MediaElement

Tags: wpf

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что не получается указать относительный путь к видео файлу в MediaElement. Например пишу:

```
media1.Source = new Uri(@"Videos\VideoForTest.mp4", UriKind.Absolute);
```

И всё равно не работает, но когда я пишу полный путь всё работает.

Как это исправить? Срочно надо

Comment: В данном случае следует использовать UriKind.Relative

Comment: Тоже не работает

Comment: Попробовал у себя, получилось, что относительный путь ссылается на место где находится ехе-файл, в общем получилось с путем `@"..\..\Videos\VideoForTest.mp4"`, не знаю насколько это правильный выход из ситуации.

Comment: Либо скопируйте папку Videos в папку Debug программы, и все будет работать с Вашим путем.